# Why does EF Core throws "Database already exists"?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-core-2.2

My start-up conditions:

1. I have an application on .Net Core using EF Core (both 2.2);
2. I have an existing database on local SQLServer;
3. I use built-in DI to supply my DbContext: `services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString))`;
4. I use Fluent API to configure my context (empty method to start with) and `DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options` constructor;
5. I have **several** migrations from other projects **existing in Database** and **no existing in my current project**.

Using all of mentioned I perform (`dotenet ef migrations add Initial --project ../MyDALProject`) on an empty model to get an empty Initial Migration. That works fine. Then I run `dotenet ef database update --project ../MyDALProject` to apply this Empty Migration to the database. Nevertheless, I get *"Database 'TargetDatabase' already exists. Choose a different database name"*.

BTW.: other projects work with the same Db just as fine.

What can be the problem? How to make it works?

P.S.: other projects' contextes, I have mentioned, are been scaffolded and mapped to some existing tables. After scaffold, migrations and updates work as expected. The problem relys only to this project, which will bring new tables to an existing db.

Comment: have a look here: https://www.ryadel.com/en/entity-framework-core-migrations-error-database-already-exists-fix-migrate-ef-dotnet/

Comment: @JohnB, I have read it, but as I understood it works in cases when I drop database before migrating it. I don't want to drop db any time I need to migrate it., i.e. at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all, I decided to apply scripts to db manually and then found out, that db was inaccessible... Finally, I restored it and everything ran perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I renamed the database directory which contains the mdf and logs directory.
Had to give it back its name to get the migration working.

Still inaccessibility issues.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).